# How do I take desktop screenshot within Windows Embedded Standard?

Tags: windows, screenshot, embedded

I have a computer running Windows Embedded Standard OS with a specific application on it. There is no MS Paint or snipping tool, but I need to take a screenshot of the application. How do I take a screenshot within Windows Embedded OS?

Comment: This will be closed, but I use Greenshot.

Comment: Thanks for answering but why will it be closed? I'll try Greenshot. Thanks!

Comment: @Xavierjazz: So you use Greenshot on Windows Embedded and know it works fine?

Comment: @karan I tested it and it works beautifully. If Xavierjazz list it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Xavierjazz this is a valid question for SU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you try Greenshot: http://getgreenshot.org/